# textviewで配列を使ってページごとの表記を変えたい

Tags: swift

Swiftでtextviewを使った質問です。

labelとbuttonとtextviewを設置している状態で、
buttonは2つあり、「next」「previous」とあります。

各ページに内容の違うtextviewを配列を使って設定したいのですが、
どうコーディングしたらよいでしょうか。

Comment: 「各ページ」というのは同じレイアウトのビューコントローラーを複数用意するということでしょうか？それともボタン押下でビューを変更するということでしょうか？もし前者であればそもそも配列は不要な気がします。

Comment: 後者ですね。ビューコントローラーは一つです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純に表示を変えるだけならインスタンス変数で配列とインデックスを保持して表示内容を切り替えれば良いと思います。

インスタンス変数

```
let array = ["１番目のテキスト", "２番目のテキスト", "３番目のテキスト", "４番目のテキスト", "５番目のテキスト"]
var lastIndex = 0
var currentIndex = 0
```

アクション

```
@IBAction func touchUpPrevious(sender: UIButton) {
    if (currentIndex == 0) { return }
    currentIndex--
    self.textView.text = array[currentIndex]
}

@IBAction func touchUpNext(sender: UIButton) {
    if (lastIndex <= currentIndex) { return }
    currentIndex++
    self.textView.text = array[currentIndex]
}
```

ページングさせたいならこの辺が参考になりそうです。

[Scroll View with Paging Tutorial in iOS8 with Swift](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/scroll-view-paging-tutorial-ios8-swift)
英語のサイトですが図やソースコードが多いですし、最後にGitHubへのリンクもあります。

[[iPhone] UIScrollView ページ スクロール](https://akira-watson.com/iphone/uiscrollview_page_scroll.html)  
こちらは日本語ですが、Objective-Cのサンプルです。